# SQL Server Source Control

Tags: sql-server, version-control

When we first started source control the developers would just edit the scripts in the database and right before the release one big script of all the changes would be made.  This worked great until one of the devs accidently deleted a stored procedure and all the work was lost.

After that we put all the scripts to create the stored procedures in text files and stored them in source control.  The problem here is that the developers sometimes update the stored procedure in source control or the database and forget to update the other one.

My dream is to have a system where a dev goes in and checks out a stored procedure.  Then after changes are made the database is automatically updated.

Is this just a dream?  What is the best way to source control SQL Server?

Comment: That's a big problem, I have asked lots of time, but no good answer yet, the only answer seems to be coordinating it through operational procedures.

Comment: We created http://tessik.com/sqlhistorian for this very reason: relying on a dev to update their version control against what they already did in the db is an exercise in futility. Our system automatically records the change to source control once the T-SQL hits the server, without any additional user interaction.

Comment: Many companies **dont allow** developers to apply scripts directly into production, so I believe the best scenario is to allow (a DBA) to update **from scripts to the database** and not the other way round. However, in real world it's possible that someone don't follow correctly the change procedures, so **the best is to allow bidirectional comparison. Try this free tool:** [http://servantt.com](http://servantt.com/?so) - it allows you to reverse engineer your objects, save to scripts, compare database to scripts, launch WinMerge for comparison, update scripts or apply changes to the database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have been using [Visual Studio Team System Database Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/11/25/visual-studio-team-system-2008-database-edition-gdr-rtm.aspx) recently, and I have to say it has worked very well.  All stored procedures are stored as files, and checked in and out of source control, and it has tools to generate scripts, etc.

Also, in the past we've used scripts stored as text files that are checked in and out of source control.  The rule was that you had to check out the file, then edit it in, for instance, Management Studio, and save it, and check it back in.  At the top of every stored procedure script file it would drop the existing stored proc, and then use the CREATE statement to create a new one (gets around the CREATE/ALTER problem).  We then had a tool that would run all the scripts in the right order to build a blank database from scratch, and then we used RedGate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/SQL_Compare/index_beta.htm) product to generate a script to bring our existing databases up to date.  I admit it was tedious.

Around the same time I worked on a system with about 10 other developers, and they implemented a rigorous database change management procedure.  There were many, many applications that all depended on a set of 2 or 3 databases.  Any time a database schema had to change (we're only talking tables, columns and views here) then a document was created that explained the change, and then there was a matrix that listed the changes vs. what applications we thought it would impact.  Then the document was circulated and had to be reviewed by someone responsible for each application, and they had to search through their application for anywhere it might be impacted, etc.  It was a long arduous procedure, but it worked.  However, stored procs were just stored as text files in source control.

In the more distant past, with smaller projects that were more like desktop apps with a database as the datastore, every time the app started, I would:

- Check to see if the database existed, and if not, create it
- Check that all the tables existed, and if not, create them
- Check that all the columns existed, and if not, add them

Whenever I needed to change the schema, I would just add more code to the end of the startup code to modify the schema as necessary, taking care to migrate any existing data.  The benefit of this was that you could just uninstall and reinstall a new version of the software, and it would automatically upgrade the existing database to the latest version.  Installation, upgrades, and maintenance was a dream.  That wouldn't work for more "enterprisey" systems though.

You can reduce some of these problems by adopting ADO.Net Entities or another similar Entity Framework, like [Entity Spaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Default.aspx).  These are object-relational mapping layers.  They auto-generate classes for each entity (table) in your database, including properties for each column, etc.  Then they allow you to extend those classes with custom logic.  If you can get away from having your business logic in stored procedures, and put them in the Entity classes, then the benefit is that they're strongly typed.  Therefore if you change the name of a column, or delete a column and you regenerate your entity classes, then your IDE or compiler will automatically flag all the places where the code is broken.  Obviously, all the entity code is naturally in source control with the rest of your source code too.

Comment: Database Edition, specially the new builds coming out recently, is a great tool not only for version control, but also to flag bad practices, to help with schema changes and refactoring and not least to help with the deployment process on end-user site.

Comment: @Remus - yes, and I was impressed that it finds errors like old stored procs that are referencing a non-existent column in some long forgotten table, etc.  It really helped clean things up.

Comment: Try this free tool: [http://servantt.com](http://servantt.com/?so) - it allows you to reverse engineer your objects, save to scripts, compare database to scripts, launch WinMerge for comparison, update scripts or apply changes to the database. It can't handle complex scenarios as yours, but can probably fit into many other companies.

Answer (score 8):

Red Gate SQL Source Control fully integrates source control to SQL Server Management Studio. This effectively links your development database(s) to your existing source control system (TFS and SVN) allowing commiting of changes and retrieving other developers' changes at the click of a button.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/

We've now added VSS and SourceGear Vault support to an EA version. More details here: http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=12265

Comment: It's worth noting that Red Gate no longer supporting VSS due to Microsoft's impending End of Life.

Comment: Its worth mentioning too that Red-Gate's TFS implementation does not directly support policies such as association of work items to checkins. They do have an implementation but it is tedious.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've seen source control work best for SQL Server in a team environment was when the DBA did regular builds of the database using checked-in code.  It generally only takes a single instance of losing something because it wasn't checked-in before developers get the picture that checking-in their code means something.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I've worked in an environment where source control was part of the release procedure.

DBAs were given release notes that required the DBA to get from source control and then release stored procedure changes or SQL scripts from there.  If you can get the DBAs on side then this is a good way of avoiding aborted releases, as you should be able to pretest the SQL on a UAT system.

If the data is not released into source control then it doesn't get released.

Integration branches were used to release the code.

Answer (score 0):

We have always used the scptxfr utility that comes with SQL Server 2000 to script the database out to a file that is stored under source control.

We run it before doing a check in and it will highlight any chances that have occurred (whether expected or not). It does not come with 2005 or later, but if you have any old 2000 install it still works against the newer versions. It can have problems with complex schemas but it is a good starting place. It could also be made an automatic process when combined with source control triggers or Continuous Integration.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to limit right to prod to only a few individuals and to insist that they do not ever make changes except by calling up a script from source control. In newere versions of SQl Server you can also set up DDL logging to find out exactly who changed that table to a version not in Source Control!

When we first made the switch to using source control on our database everyone had prod rights (something we have since fixed), so we had a dba periodically do compare of source control check ins with the actual prod database and get rid of any unauthorized changes. It only took doing it once to convince the developers that they had to use source control.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a script to help us solve this problem - it's not complete source control by any stretch, but it's just a single stored procedure that stores the history of your database objects in a table - you can schedule it using the SQL Agent to run as often as you want.

While it will take snapshots at a point in time, it doesn't really support check-ins, but it has saved our bacon a few times when a stored proc gets dropped or changed without a backup, and the previous version is easily restored.

http://trycatchfinally.net/2011/06/roll-your-own-lightweight-sql-server-source-control/

Answer (score 0):

Getting developers to remember to commit code is tricky.

The other end of it is a bit easier because once the updates are in source control they can be automated with scripts to build a new database / or drop and recreate a database from source control.

Check out this free [product](http://gitsql.net/documentation-04_SQL_Server_and_GIT) which will help set up a baseline of an SQL Server database.

The tool will also build a DB from source control - so in theory, you can have X developers working on the project and they can all be running each others commits from source into their own database - and vice versa, rolling out their updates back into source control.

Unfortunately, - I can't think of how to get the developers to remember to commit DB changes. Perhaps they could run a tool (or batch file) that will perform a pull of local database to source control and then get into the habit of running this repetitive task via a batch file - each time they come to doing a pull/commit in source control?